# How to open another View from links within UIWebview in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, xcode8

As i implemented the code in which it perfectly work on Browser that is open the safari in ios and put  `myapp://` on address bar it open my app but i want when click on link which is inside `UIWebView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let setURL=URL(string:"https://myapp.com/")
    let setURLRequest=URLRequest(url:setURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(setURLRequest)

}
```

this is my code for loading website into webview and added `URL TYPE >item0->myapp`

```
item0->URL Scheme->myapp
```

when i add to link eg `< a href="myapp://"></a>` it does not launch the another view getting errors

**Appdelegate**

```
     public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if request.url?.scheme == "myapp" {
         // UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!, options: [:], //completionHandler: nil)
let myVC: MyAnotherController = MyAnotherController() 
self.present(myVC, animated: true) { } 
            return false
        }
    return true
}
```

**getting this error Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'present'"**

Comment: Get the reference of a viewcontroller that is already on screen (using root view controller, if your app has one or by any other provision (if your app has any)), and then call present method on it.

Comment: but how it is possible its opening the myapp application even i dont mentioned "UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!, options: [:], //completionHandler: nil)" what should i do ?

Comment: Could you upload your project somewhere (preferrably Google drive) and share the link?

Comment: here or on your email id

Comment: It's upto you. This is my email id: saurabhbhatia.jmi@gmail.com

Comment: yeah done just check it thanx in advance

Comment: Replied with the fix to the issue, hope it works for you.

Comment: Hello @Saurabh it did not work i mean it again opening application not anotherController

Comment: Umesh, I hope its working now

Comment: great .. it work now :) @SaurabhBhatia i really appreciate your time and solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inside **if block**, you need to **return false**, and it should work.
By returning false the delegate method tells that the webView should not start loading the url.

```
public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

if request.url?.scheme == "myapp" {
    // do your work here
    UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    //Add the below line of code to the existing code
    return false
}
return true
```

}

Comment: i did add myapp in plist file for myapp application and webview in another application and i want that when i click on link which in anotther app myapp should open but it also not working by setting return false

Comment: In case i need to open another view in same app

Comment: What do you mean by another view?

Comment: i mean another storyboard eg click on button (Webview) open another view on same application not another application

Comment: Replace UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil) with the statement that would present another view controller. 
Example:         let myVC: MyViewController = MyViewController()
        self.present(baseVC, animated: true) {
            
        }

Comment: self.present (myVC,animated:true) or self.present(baseVC, animated: true) { }

Comment: Yeah, my bad. That's a typo. It should be myVC.

Comment: but its getting error that "  Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'present' "

Comment: This works on an instance of UIViewController, not AppDelegate.

Comment: so how could i add into AppDeletegate file

Comment: Could you edit your question with some more code, to tell what exactly you are trying?

Comment: now i tested that application is opening even i dont mentioned " UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UIWebView` delegate method `optional public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool`

**Example**

```
public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if request.url?.scheme == "myapp" {
        // do your work here
        UIApplication.shared.open(request.url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    return true
}
```

But you have to mention all the desire schemes in your app plist too..

[image]

Open other apps using url schemes

```
if let url = URL.init(string: "myapp://") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        print("scheme is missing in info.plist or invalid scheme")
    }
} else {
    print("invalid url")
}
```

Comment: then how do we launch the app ?

Comment: yes i did all setting in plist file ...i understand ...that mean according you i need to open the safari and hit the url so that app can launch

Comment: I think i miss understood your question.. if you just want to open other app you don't have to open the web view, just use this `UIApplication.shared.open(request.url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` and add the schemes in your info.plist.

Comment: Thank you :) Actually im new to Swift 3 IOS App Developement do you have good article for tutorial i ll appreciate for that

Comment: it does not working ..dont know but when i click on button as link and pass "myapp://" this url

Comment: actually copy that code and paste into UIViewController

Comment: Try this answer. It should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44216311/5237727

Comment: In case i need to open another view in same app

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (It will work if the URL's last character contains "#"). "#" is added because if we navigate back to the last screen, it does not open.

link(www.google.com) in web view.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
    navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    // request.url?.absoluteString = "www.google.com/#"
    let last = request.url?.absoluteString.last
    if last == "#" {
       //do stuff here
    }
    return true
}
```